# Docker Container (Website) Content not Updating

Tags: docker, apache, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers

I have built a project with a webhost (httpd:2.4)

(Dockerfile Content:
`FROM httpd:2.4`
`COPY . /usr/local/apache2/htdocs` )

It's hosting a static website... and I'd like to be able to change that / publish future changes but that doesn't work in the way I was expecting it to...

I'm using

```
git clone [repository]
cd [repository]
docker-compose -f docker-compose/docker-compose.yml up -d
```

to run the project, which works perfectly fine

The problem is that I should be able to make changes to the website.
I supposed it would just work like that:

`docker-compose -f docker-compose/docker-compose.yml down`
changing the index.html (save)
`docker-compose -f docker-compose/docker-compose.yml up -d`

But even though (for the test) I deleted every single character in my index.html, it still shows up exactly the same as before

What am I missing? What commands would I have to run for the changes to get applied?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dockerfile, the file containing the below,

```
FROM httpd:2.4
COPY . /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
```

It means you are building a custom docker image for your need. And you are also using the `COPY` command to copy the project to your docker image which is **done** when building the custom docker image. This is a good solution to copy the code in the docker image for distribution purposes however might not be the best for development purposes.

If changes are made to the project, this is not reflected in the custom docker image until that docker image is **rebuilt**. After rebuilding the image, the current files of the project are copied to the docker image. Then after restarting the docker compose and by also using the latest image built, the changes will be visible.

If you do not want to build a docker image each time a change is made, it might be best to create a docker-compose file which will map your project directly to `/usr/local/apache2/htdocs`. This way when the changes made to the project will be reflected instantly without any build process.

Sample docker compose file with the project mapping to `/usr/local/apache2/htdocs`, this docker compose file needs to be located in the directory where the `index.html` lives.

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  apache:
    image: httpd:latest
    container_name: webserver
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    volumes:
      # mapping your root project's directory to htdocs
      - ${PWD}:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs
```

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm being an idiot here... but this gives me the error message:

time="2023-02-13T15:54:01+01:00" level=warning msg="The \"PWD\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
1 error(s) decoding:
* error decoding 'Volumes[0]': invalid spec: :/usr/local/apache2/htdocs: empty section between colons

also... how is the docker image rebuilt, then? I thought that's what I was doing with docker-compose down - make changes - up
Or are the dockerfile and docker-compose.yml not related at all? and would I not need a dockerfile at all with your code?
Sorry I'm new to all this

Comment: You will need a docker file to build and distribute your docker image. Doing a docker-compose up will start running the docker image as a docker container (it can build a new docker image as well but I would not recommend it). Doing a docker-compose down simply stop running your docker container. If you make changes to the project, but do no build a new docker image, nothing will happen. 

`${PWD}` is a linux command to print your current directory, you can use the absolute path of the directory as well to do the mapping, `/c/Users/username/Desktop/project/x:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs`.

Answer (score 0):

This problem may arise if you have referenced a docker image inside your docker-compose.yml file instead of building the image there. When you reference an image, `docker-compose up` will create the corresponding containers with the exact same image.

You need to:

- Build the image again AFTER you have made changes to your html file and BEFORE running docker-compose.

OR

- Build the image inside docker-compose.yml like [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/#step-3-define-services-in-a-compose-file)